# break lines for each new set of data

Tags: java

I want new customerName and new line

```
try
      {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));

         String line;
         //bw.write("Customer Record: \r\n");

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
         {
            if (line.contains(customerName))
            {
                customerRecordPresentInFile = true;
                line = line + "," + billAmountPayable;
            }
            //bw.write("\r\n");
```

I am using this lines of code, but my output in file is everything is on one line, i want to break line.

```
    bw.write(line + "\n");
  }
```

please make some change in code.

```
  if(!customerRecordPresentInFile)
  {
     bw.write(customerName + "-" + billAmountPayable + "\n");
  }
  System.out.println("\nData file updated.");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
    try
    {
        if(br != null) { br.close(); }
        if(bw != null) { bw.close(); }
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the newLine() method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

`\n` is platform specific

Answer (score 0):

As per source of Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()) `newLine()` method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator. Not all platforms use the newline character ('\n') to terminate lines. Calling this method to terminate each output line is therefore preferred to writing a newline character directly

try this code .

```
 bw.write(line);
  bw.newLine();
```

and

```
 if(!customerRecordPresentInFile)
         {
             bw.write(customerName + "-" + billAmountPayable);
             bw.newLine();
         }
```

instead of `bw.write(line + "\n");`